# Using Dispatch Event to check authorization

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to setup a simple API. I have a Controller all other API controllers are extending, and I have attached a dispatch listener like so. I created a test that will always fail. Set the status code to 401, and return a message. However, it's still calling the main Controller method and not abandoning the request from the preDispatch method. Can I build a proper response here and force ZF2 not to continue executing the requested route? I tried just adding an `exit()` statement, but the client side receives an incomplete response.

```
protected function attachDefaultListeners()
    {
        parent::attachDefaultListeners();
        $events = $this->getEventManager();
        $this->events->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'preDispatch'), 100);
        $this->events->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'postDispatch'), -100);
    }

    public function preDispatch (MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $this->dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
        // TODO: Check user and token from DB
        if (Cookie::isCookieSet())
        {
            $cookie = Cookie::readCookie();
            if (empty($cookie->user))
            {
                $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(401);
                return new JsonModel(array('auth' => false, 'msg' => 'Try again'));
            }
        // Cookie not set, if we are authenticating, continue; otherwise return a failure
        } else {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a response object to short circuit the process, not a ViewModel:

Try something like this:

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setStatusCode(401);
$response->setContent(array('auth' => false, 'msg' => 'Try again'));
return $response;
```